# pointwise convergence of sequence of function

Tags: lebesgue-integral, sequence-of-function, pointwise-convergence

I need some help with this exercise: Let 
$n \in N$ and $f_n:[0,1]\Rightarrow R$ with $f_n(x):=\frac{n^\alpha \cdot \ x}{1+n^2x^2}$, and $\alpha\ge0$
a) For which $\alpha$ is $f_n$ pointwise convergent on $[0,1]$? And what is $f$ in this case? Is $f$ L-integrable on $[0,1]$?

I tried the convergents for $\alpha=0,\alpha=1,\alpha=2$ and so i think it convergent for $\alpha\le1$ because for $\alpha=2$ I have $1/x$ which i dont definied for $x=0$

Maybe you can help me, because if its convergent I can maybe use Lebesgue theorem of  dominated convergence or monton convergence theorem

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It converges pointwise if $0\leqslant\alpha\leqslant2$. If $\alpha\in[0,2)$, it converges pointwise to the null function and, if $\alpha=2$, it converges pointwise to$$\begin{array}{ccc}[0,1]&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\x&\mapsto&\begin{cases}0&\text{ if }x=0\\\frac1x&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}\end{array}$$If $\alpha>3$, it doesn't converge pointwise.

In particular, your sequence converges pointwise to a Lebesgue-integrable function if and only if $\alpha\in[0,2)$.

Comment: And it its Lebesgue-integrable for $\alpha \in [0,2)$ because the null function is integrable, aren't t?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: Thanks al lot, maybe you can help me with the other questions too, because im not sure if you can rlly answer them so easily like i thought, hope im not bothering.

Comment: Which other question?

Comment: b) determine $M_n:=max_x\in[0,1] f_n(x)$ and calculate $\int_0^1f_n(x)dx$

Okay, would say the maximum is $1$ and i only can calculate the integral if i can change $lim$ and the $\int$ so this is only possible for $\alpha \in [0,2)$ where $f_n$ convergets to the null function so the integral equals zero? 
c) For which $\alpha$ can you do this: $lim \int_0^1 f_n(x)dx$ $=$$\int_0^1f(x)dx$ 
Here I also would say, only for $\alpha \in 
[0,2)$

Comment: d) For which $\alpha$ are the conditions of the theorem of dominated convergency accomplished, the same one as before i would say, because we need convergency for $f_n$

Comment: Sorry, added it first as a an Answer for this post

Comment: No, I shall answer no more questions. If you think that I did not answer your original question, that's fine. If you think that I did, then please mark my answer as the accepted one.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, but of course you answered my original question, but then i'll will make a new thread with the other questions, thanks.

Comment: And if I know how to answer them, I will.